# Loop through a string with jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading a simple txt file from the same server as the current web page using jQuery - this file will always include a plain number with no formatting - e.g. 123456

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

  var test;
  $.getJSON('myfile.txt', function(data) {
    test = data;
    showAlert(); // this call will display actual value
  });

  function showAlert() {
    alert(test);
  }

});
```

At the moment, the code pulls the file in and then shows the content in an alert box but what I want to do is read through the response character by character and create an HTML string which I can then insert in to the page - each character would be converted to an image tag.

For example if the response was 123 I want to create a string holding the following HTML:

```
<img src="1.png" />
<img src="2.png" />
<img src="3.png" />
```

And then I will insert that string into a div on my page.

Can anybody suggest how to go about looping through the response to create the img tags?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I love [`jQuery.map`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.map) for stuff like this. Just map (ie convert) each number to a snippet of html:

```
var images = jQuery.map((1234567 + '').split(''), function(n) {
  return '<img src="' + n + '.png" />'
})

images[0]; // <img src="1.png" />
images[1]; // <img src="2.png" />
images[2]; // <img src="3.png" />
// etc...
```

which you can then `join('')` and jam into the DOM in one swift punch:

```
$('#sometarget').append(images.join(''))
```

And bob's your uncle.

Comment: @Eric: thanks for leaving a comment. So you know, when a question is tagged with 'jquery' it is acceptable for answers to utilize jQuery. The presumption is the OP wishes to learn more about the technologies they tag a question with.

Answer (score 66):

To loop through the characters in a string you would do this:

```
var s = '123456';
for ( var i = 0; i < s.length; i++ )
{
  // `s.charAt(i)` gets the character
  // you may want to do a some jQuery thing here, like $('<img...>')
  document.write( '<img src="' + s.charAt(i) + '.png" />' );
}
```

Comment: @Eric jQuery was mentioned in the question, but I agree it shouldn't be used when there is a much simpler solution like this. jQuery.map can be elegant, but it doesn't seem like it in this particular case.

Comment: +1 because I was looking for a loop over a string, not `jQuery.map` - even though that's useful, just not what I needed.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a regular expression that matches a single character, and replace each character with an image tag that contains the character:

```
var html = data.replace(/(.)/g, '<img src="$1.png" />')
```

The pattern `.` matches a single character, the parentheses around it makes it a match to output, the `g` option stands for global so that it replaces all mathces, not just the first one. The `$1` marker in the replacement string is where the match output (the character) will be placed.

Comment: What's the downvote for? It's rather pointless if you don't explain what it is that you don't agree with...

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to show a few different ways to iterate over the characters in a string `str` using only native JavaScript functionality.

### Plain for loop

The good old ES3 way. This will work in browsers as old as IE 6.

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    var chr = str.charAt(i);
    alert(chr);
}
```

### forEach on split array

ES5 compatible.

```
str.split('').forEach(function (chr) {
    console.log(chr);
});
```

### forEach on string

ES5 compatible. Will perform a little faster than the previous method for large strings.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(str, function (chr) {
    console.log(chr);
});
```

### for-of loop

Runs in new browsers only. Requires ES6 support.

```
for (var chr of str) {
    console.log(chr);
}
```

---

As a note, in some common cases bulk operations over the characters in a string are better performed without an iteration using functional programming paradigms.
For example, to retrieve an array from the characters in a string, `str.split('')` is enough, or with ES6 syntax `[...str]`.
To map the characters in a string like array elements, it's much better to call `Array.prototype.map` directly on the string:

```
Array.prototype.map.call(str, function (chr) {
    return '<img src="' + chr + '.png" />';
});
```

Answer (score 3):

## Simplest string for-in loop:

```js
const str = 'ABC123'

for (let i in str)
  console.log( str[i] )
```